# Best way to integrate R and Flash/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, r

I want to make a Flash or Flex front end for my R code, I want to call an R function from a website (using Flash) what is the best way to go about connecting Flash and R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't directly address your need, but the [animation package also allows you to create flash output](http://animation.yihui.name/animation:start), but just of static animations.  [Here are the slides from UseR! last year](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2008/slides/Xie.pdf).

*Edit:* You should also check out [this blog post from David Smith](http://blog.revolution-computing.com/2009/06/animate-r-graphics-with-flash.html).

Answer (score 7):

Duncan Temple Lang has a package [FlashMXML](http://www.omegahat.org/FlashMXML) that it provides (and I quote):

- various graphics devices for R that generate the plot as ActionScript code that can be displayed within a Flash application, and
- tools to generate MXML content from R data
- an R function for compiling MXML files to SWF binaries to be run by a Flash Player in a Web browser or stand-alone.

Comment: for some reason the server directory is empty.. are there any other copies of the package?